# lisp: function that takes an initial list and diffs it against additional lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Still trying to recreate lodash in lisp as a way of getting familiar with the language. This time I need both algorithmic and syntactic help.

Trying to recreate the `_.difference` function, which, in lisp, would create a list of values in an input list not included in the other given lists, while maintaining order of the original list.

```
_.difference((2, 1), (2, 3));
// => (1)
```

Not sure how to approach this one, I basically want to be able to pop values out of an `initial-list` list as I traverse through subsequent lists.

Comment: as a straightforward approach, you can just loop over `initial-list`, if you can't `find` an element in the other lists, then `collect` it

Comment: Makes sense, how do you track whether an element isn't found in any subsequent lists?

Comment: I would write a function that just finds the difference of two lists -- then fold or reduce across all the lists -- the subsequent differences are commutative

Comment: would you mind writing some skeleton code to illustrate? Part of the issue is that I don't know what the right way to do that in lisp is.

Comment: Note: reducing with `set-difference` is not correct as the question is posed, because it doesn't guarantee order.

Answer (score 4):

A straigtforward approach could use a simple function to loop over a list and collect the elements that aren't in another list (if you aren't trying to implement it yourself, there is `set-difference`).  `reduce` can be used to apply this function to the set of lists.

```
(defun my-diff (l1 l2)
  (loop for x in l1
     unless (find x l2)
     collect x))

(reduce #'my-diff '((2 1 4 3 5) (2 3) (2 0 1)))
;; => (4 5)
```

Comment: The upside to this is that it’s simple. The downside to this function is that it’s O(nm) with n, m being the sizes of the input lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly obvious implementation which will have good performance for large lists (and makes no pretence to purity of implementation):

```
(defun differences (l1 &rest ls)
  ;; This assumes EQL
  (loop with table = (make-hash-table)
        initially (loop for l in ls
                        do (loop for e in l
                                 do (setf (gethash e table) t)))
          for e in l1
          unless (gethash e table nil)
          collect e))
```

Here's a similar version which might do better if the lists are either small or there are few unique elements:

```
(defun differences (l1 &rest ls)
  ;; This assumes EQL
  (loop with uniques = ()
        initially (loop for l in ls
                        do (loop for e in l
                                 do (pushnew e uniques)))
          for e in l1
          unless (member e uniques)
          collect e))
```

Comment: This is good if `l1` is larger than the sum of the lengths of the other lists. If that is not true you can do the reverse: make a hashset from the elements of `l1`, iterate through the rest removing those elements from the hashset (you could also keep a count of elements left so you can short-circuit if everything is removed), then pass over `l1` again dropping elements not in your hashset. It is perhaps also worth mentioning something about equality testing. This used `eql` which is similar to JavaScript’s equality except that in JS, strings are compared as `string=` does in CL and `1 == "1"`

Comment: @DanRobertson: Unfortunately it's more complicated than that.  First of all you can't pick which algorithm you would like without walking all the lists once, which you don't want to do.  Even then yours walks the lists more than mine does (`l1` twice, each other list once), & computes the same number of hashes (unless you do the count trick, when it may compute less).  The number of hashtable entries actually created then depends on the number of unique elements which is another thing you can't know in advance.

Comment: Sure, I don’t want to suggest that the method I described is always faster, or that one could pick a faster method at runtime, just that there are reasons one might want one Mathis instead of another

Answer (score 1):

Using tail recursion:

```
(defun difference (l1 l2 &key (acc '()) (test #'eql))
  (cond ((null l1) (nreverse acc))
        ((null l2) (nreverse (append (reverse l1) acc)))
        ((member (car l1) l2 :test test) (difference (cdr l1) l2 :acc acc :test test))
        (t (difference (cdr l1) l2 :acc (cons (car l1) acc) :test test))))
```

Using mutation:

```
(defun difference (l1 l2 &key (test #'eql))
  (let ((res l1))
    (dolist (x l2 res)
      (setf res (remove x res :test test)))))
```

For such kind of function which has to compare elements in a list,
it is convention in common lisp, to introduce an optional `&key` which is
called `test`.

Equality tests in lisp are more complicated than in other languages.
So take care of them.

In short:

```
|equality of objects (identity)|#'eq|
|objects (#'eq) and numbers (type dependent) and characters (case sensitive)|#'eql|
|numeric equality (type independent)|#'=|
|character equality (case sensitive)|#'char=|
|string equality (case sensitive)|#'string=|
|#'eql or strings of eql characters or bit vectors of the same contents or lists of equal objects. For other data types #'eq.|#'equal|
|more advanced equality: #'equal objects or numbers (type independent) or characters (case insensitive) or strings (case insensitive). Lists, hashes, arrays and structures are #'equalp if all their elements are #'equalp. For everything else #'eq is used.|#'equalp|
```